# rails own resources controller and form for error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource

I have database table `store`

model name **models/store/store.rb**

```
class Store::Store < ActiveRecord::Base
...
end
```

controller **controllers/store/maintenance_controller.rb**

```
class Store::MaintenanceController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @stores = Store.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @stores }
    end
  end

  def new
    @store = Store.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @store }
    end
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  namespace :store do
    root :to => "store#index"
    resources :store, :path => 'maintenance', controller: 'maintenance', :as => 'maintenance'
  end
```

**rake routes |grep store**

```
      store_root        /store(.:format)                                           store/store#index
  store_maintenance_index GET    /store/maintenance(.:format)                               store/maintenance#index
                        POST   /store/maintenance(.:format)                               store/maintenance#create
    new_store_maintenance GET    /store/maintenance/new(.:format)                           store/maintenance#new
   edit_store_maintenance GET    /store/maintenance/:id/edit(.:format)                      store/maintenance#edit
        store_maintenance GET    /store/maintenance/:id(.:format)                           store/maintenance#show
                        PUT    /store/maintenance/:id(.:format)                           store/maintenance#update
                        DELETE /store/maintenance/:id(.:format)                           store/maintenance#destroy
```

if i enter localhost:3000/store
its work but if i enter localhost:3000/store/new im getting error
`undefined method 'stores_path' for`
on line
`<%= form_for(@store) do |f| %>`

what is wrong here ? Thank you (i already have store controller thats why i have to rename controller for store table if i want to use scaffolding)

Comment: What is your Rails version?

Comment: rails -v returns 3.2.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form looks for a `POST` to `stores_path`, but it's `store_maintenance_index_path` where your route goes for the create action. So there is no `stores_path`.

Your setup isn't right..

You don't have any routes resources for `stores`, only for `maintenances`..

So the real question is, what are you trying to CRUD? Is it `maintenances` or `stores`?

If you want to CRUD `stores`, edit your routes to:

```
namespace :store do
  resources :stores
end
```

If you really want to edit the pathname to maintenance, something like this:

```
namespace :store do
  resources :stores, path: 'maintenances', controller: 'stores', as: 'stores'
end
```

You don't want to CRUD `stores` in a `maintenances` controller, that's just not right...

Comment: i want CRUD store table but crud actions have in maintance controller because im using store controller for anything else it is possible ??

Comment: ok i will think about it maybe i will rename store controller

Comment: If you really want this, you could have a `StoreController`, and a `StoresController`, single and plural. But my advise would be one controller per model. Also if it's only the pathnames you're worried about, than just use a `scope` for `/store`. And find out more information about routing in general..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to move your `models/store/store.rb` to `models/store.rb`, then change the line to:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
...
end
```